# Shell script for finding (and deleting) video files if they came from a rar

Tags: shell, rar

My download program automatically unrars rar archives, which is all well and good as Sonarr and Radarr need that original video file to import. But now my download HDD fills up with all these video files I no longer need.

I've tried playing around with modifying existing scripts I have, but every step seems to take me further from the goal.

Here's what I have so far (that isnt working and I clearly dont know what im doing). My main problem is I can't get it to find the files correctly yet. This script jumps right to "no files found". So I'm doing the search wrong at the very least. Or I'm pretty sure I might need to completely rewrite from scratch using a different method I'm not aware of..

```
#!/bin/bash
# Find video files and if it came from a rar, remove it. 

# If no directory is given, work in local dir
if [ "$1" = "" ]; then
  DIR="."
else
  DIR="$1"
fi

# Find all the MKV files in this dir and its subdirs
find "$DIR" -type f -name '*.mkv' | while read filename

do

# If video file and rar file exists, delete mkv.

for f in ...
do
    if [[ -f "$DIR/*.mkv" ]] && [[ -f "$DIR/*.rar" ]]
    then
#   rm $filename
    printf "[Dry run delete]: $filename\n"
    else
    printf "No files found\n"
    exit 1
fi
done
```

Example of directory structure before and after. Note the file names are often different to the extracted file. And I want to leave other folders that don't have rars in them alone.

Before:

```
/folder/moviename/Movie.that.came.from.rar.2021.dvdrip.mkv
/folder/moviename/movie.rar
/folder/moviename/movie.r00
/folder/moviename/movie.r01

/folder/moviename2/Movie.that.lives.alone.2021.dvdrip.mkv
/folder/moviename2/Movie.2021.dvdrip.nfo
```

After

```
# (deleted the mkv only from the first folder)
/folder/moviename/movie.rar
/folder/moviename/movie.r00
/folder/moviename/movie.r01

# (this mkv survives)
/folder/moviename2/Movie.that.lives.alone.2021.dvdrip.mkv
/folder/moviename2/Movie.2021.dvdrip.nfo
```

TL:DR I would like a script to look recursively in my download drive for video files and rar files, and if it sees both in the same folder, delete the video file.

Comment: Can you provide more detail that "that isn't working"?

Comment: Sorry for being vague, ive changed the script a lot and get different failures. In this above example it skips right to "no files found". I believe my main problem is how im doing the "if mkv && rar" part may be wrong.

Comment: There's one `done` missing, and `for f in ...` is going to set `f` to the string `...`, which is unlikely to be what you want. Can you show a minimal representative directory tree before and after the script is run?

Comment: Yeah I struggle with the number of dones a lot.

Added a before and after to my thing. Hopefully it's clear.

Comment: What in this code is even *attempting* to "look recursively"?

Comment: Look i dont know man, that's why im asking for help.

Comment: Note that we want narrow, specific questions here -- an ideal question isn't "here's my script, here's what it's supposed to do, please help me figure out what's wrong", but "I wrote a script to do X, but the command Y doesn't have the effect Z that I'm looking for", ideally with a [mre] that (when run without changes) tests whether Y does Z with the other parts of X left out. That way you described what X _is_, so [XY questions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) can be identified, but folks can focus just on how to successfully fix Y so it does Z.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU find, you can condense this to one command:

```sh
find "${1:-.}" -type f -name '*.rar' -execdir sh -c 'echo rm *.mkv' \;
```

`${1:-.}` says "use `$1`, or `.` if `$1` is undefined or empty".

For each `.rar` file found, this starts a new shell in the directory of the file found  (that's what `-execdir sh -c '...'` does) and runs `echo rm *.mkv`.

If the list of files to delete looks correct, you can actually delete them by dropping the `echo`:

```sh
find "${1:-.}" -type f -name '*.rar' -execdir sh -c 'rm *.mkv' \;
```

Two remarks, though:

- `-execdir rm *.mkv \;` would be shorter, but then the glob might be expanded prematurely in case there are `.mkv` files in the current directory
- if a directory contains a .`rar` file, but no `.mkv`, this will try to delete a file called literally `*.mkv` and cause an error message

Comment: Thanks, I think we're on the right track.

I'm however getting the error:

find: paths must precede expression: `​-execdir'

Comment: Awesome thanks heaps, this works great. 

Thanks for your help.